# Coldfusion page executed twice

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Hi I am having a strange problem. On our development server coldfusion pages are executed twice. This happens everytime. To find out what is causing this issue, I send an email containing the request details to myself like this:

```
<Cfmail from="*" to="*" type="html"> 
<cfdump var=#GetHttpRequestData()#>
#gettickcount()#
#createUUID()#
</cfmail>
```

I get the following response when calling a page containing .cfm:

```
content [empty string] 
headers struct
TOMCATCGIHTTPURL000000006A6B0000    /test.cfm 
accept  */* 
content-length  0 
host    * 
user-agent  curl/7.40.0 

method  GET 
protocol    HTTP/1.1 
1590760731452 
C7487929-D679-B029-6E236DEE7E19B8EB
```

and a second mail containing

```
content [empty string] 
headers struct
X-Original-URL  /test.cfm
accept  */* 
content-length  0 
host    * 
user-agent  curl/7.40.0 

method  GET 
protocol    HTTP/1.1 
1590760731425 
C7487814-FA6F-4699-182C2E7382A06A47
```

Now the really strange part. When i call an index.cfm without the filename like / the page is only executed once. For example calling a page located on /test/index.cfm as /test/ returns as single response:

```
content [empty string] 
headers struct
X-Original-URL  /test/ 
accept  */* 
content-length  0 
host    * 
user-agent  curl/7.40.0 

method  GET 
protocol    HTTP/1.1 
1590762636945
C86B3A74-025F-6DBA-EA187DFEF7751F03
```

Details of environment: Windows 2016 server, IIS 10, Coldfusion 2016

Any thoughts on what is causing this issue.

**UPDATE**

I use rewrite rules. I tested disabling the rewrite rules (as suggested by Miguel-F) and then the page is executed only once. When adding a simple rewrite rule like this the page is executed twice:

```
<rule name="Test rule" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

This behavior only occurs on our development server. Our production server has none of these issues and also runs on windows 2016 IIS 10 and coldfusion 2016.

Coldfusion version for development server: 2016.0.13.316217 (Production server runs on exactly the same version and has no issues)

Comment: If you look at your http logs, do they show the same page running twice?

Comment: @DanBracuk In the IIS log the page is only loaded once.

Comment: Sounds like a connector issue. Make sure there's only one handler set up (ISAPI IIS<->Tomcat) and that there's no additional handler in Tomcat's `/cfusion/runtime/conf/server.xml`. Question is probably better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Alex I checked the server.xml file. It is identical to the same file on another server on which this problem does not occur. IIS ISAPI filters contain only one reference to tomcat. Again similar to the server on which this problem does not occur.

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules configured on the web server?  If so, disable them and try your request again to see if there is any difference. Do you have the builtin web server (Tomcat) running?  If so, request your page using that server/port and see if it still gets executed twice.  Basically trying to see if it is a web server problem or ColdFusion problem.

Comment: @Miguel-F Please see the update in my original question. How would i check whether tomcat is running or not? As far as i can tell tomcat is not running, checked by using the following command:wmic process list brief | find /i "tomcat". But i am not sure this proofs tomcat is not running.

Comment: I don't think you can find the tomcat process that way. By default the ColdFusion Tomcat port is 8500, unless it's already use, as could be the case if you have CF already running and had the built-in web server enabled for that. In that case, CF would choose 8501, 8502, or so on. So what I was suggesting is to try hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/Administrator/index.cfm` from your server to rule out IIS or any rewrite rules but it sounds like you have already found that to be the issue.

Comment: @Miguel-F Yep the rewrite rules seems to be an issue. However the question remains on how to solve this and why it is happening. Port 8500 is available for the coldfusion administrator.

Comment: Something is different between this server with the issue and those server(s) without it.  You will need to dig through the settings, configurations and versions installed to determine what the issue is. Sorry I can't pinpoint it for you but something has got to be different with this server from the others.

Comment: You should see these request in the IIS log file for your web site. What does your IIS log file show for these requests?

Comment: @Miguel-F IIS log just shows one request. Which is strange because the rules in iis are involved in the duplicate request. But calling a page like / instead of /index.cfm also works fine, whether it is redirected or not. Checked all settings I could think of but they are all equal.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but a really long comment.

You need to find out if this is one request or two. Add in some code like this:

```
  <cfparam name="request.count" default="0">
  <cfset request.count++>

  <Cfmail from="*" to="*" type="html"> 
  <cfdump var=#GetHttpRequestData()#>
  Request.count: #request.count#
  <br />
  #gettickcount()#
  #createUUID()#
  </cfmail>
```

If the file was requested twice, each email will say 1

If the file is being included somehow, then then second email will say the request count is `2`

Comment: Each email says Request.count: 1. So apparently 2 requests,

Comment: ColdFusion usually has a hiccup when one cfoutput tag is nested within another. Or, similarly, when the cfoutput tag encloses the cfmail tag, or vice versa. Make sure there are no such nested tags, especially in onRequestStart.

Comment: Oh, just the usual formality: Which ColdFusion 2016 update have you installed?

Comment: @BKBK Version 2016.0.13.316217, please also read the update in my original question. The page only contains the cfmail tag. I already tried emptying the application.cfc file but this made no change.

Comment: @Nebu, thanks. My oversight. When I look now I see the ColdFusion build number.

Comment: A possibility we had to rule out to start with: the client app or browser may be firing multiple requests. So, test by calling the CFM from a variety of clients.

Comment: @BKBK I added the version number after your comment. I already tried using different browsers on different computers (edge firefox chrome, windows 10 and windows 2016 server). The page is always executed twice. I also checked the network traffic. From the client perspective the page is called once.

Comment: Compare the following files on development and production: cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml, cfusion\runtime\conf\web.xml, WEB-INF\web.xml. Do you notice any differences between the development and production versions?

Comment: Only the WEB-INF\web.xml contained differences. When I use the WEB-INF\web.xml from the production environment on the development server the problem still occurs (did a proper restart to make sure the changes where applied).